# Writing tips for Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Is there a difference between saying that `f(n)=O(g(n))` and `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))`?

Comment: Looking at your username, I'd have assumed you have read the [**wikipedia article**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). It clearly states that both are equivalent, and that the second is more technically correct.

Comment: I wonder what is unclear about his question, why i got negative marks so that it looks -3 now?

Comment: It isn't that it is unclear. It doesn't fit on stackoverflow, and is probably better suited for http://mathematics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"=" is not meant to express "is equal to" in its normal mathematical sense, but rather a more colloquial "is", so the second expression is technically accurate!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1):

The notations with = and ∈ mean the same thing, but the former is the one that most writers actually use.

I took a look at half a dozen books that are close to hand. These books use **=**:

- de Berg et al., *Computational Geometry*
- Dasgupta et al., *Algorithms*
- Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*
- Papadimitriou & Stieglitz, *Combinatorial Optimization*

In these books I found no uses of either notation: all occurrences of O/o/Θ/Ω that I spotted were in contexts like "algorithm A is O(*n*)":

- Aho et al, *The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms*
- Ericson, *Real-Time Collision Detection*

I didn't find any occurrences of ∈.

Answer (score -1):

- The relation **"f(n) ∈ O(g(n))"** is read as "f(x) is little-o of
  g(x)".it means that g(x) grows much faster than f(x), or similarly,
  the growth of f(x) is nothing compared to that of g(x).
- It assumes that f and g are both functions of one variable. Formally,
  **f(n) = o(g(n))** as n → ∞ means that for every positive constant ε
  there exists a constant N such that f(n)<=ɛ(g(n).

Hope you got your anwer...